# The meaning of いずれ in this context

Tags: meaning

When reading a post about a game, I came across this sentence:

> 司令塔プラットフォームの最上階に赤ランプが点灯してる部屋があるんですが、ここっていずれ入れるようになるのでしょうか。

The person who posted this wanted to enter that room, but for some reason or another he couldn't.

When I looked up the meaning of いずれ, I wasn't sure if it translated along the lines of:

"**When** will I be able to enter here?" or "Will I **somehow** be able to enter here?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, 「いずれ」 means "***eventually***", "***one of these days***", "***sooner or later***", etc.

> "Will we eventually be able to enter this room?"

The larger context will reveal what the best TL would be.